# github pages Can't find variable: $

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I just created a SPA using github pages. 
It is pretty clear, as contains one `.html` with two `.js` files
I mostly use `d3.js`

I have no problem launching on local host, but have problems, when I deployed it on github pages

I have two errors:

> Can't find variable: $

and

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (HTTP/2.0 404)

Although in my index.html contains `jquery`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

https://zkid18.github.io/data_visualization_project/
https://github.com/zkid18/data_visualization_project
What's wrong?

Comment: Your page is loaded over `https` but you are trying to load jquery over `http`. This will fail. Use `https` for both.

Comment: Why the down votes? It's a legit question, he's posted a code snippet and explained expected and actual outcomes

Comment: @Lissy Probably because simply opening the browsers dev tools would have immediately shown what the problem was. This should be the first step long before asking a question on SO.

Comment: He must have opened up the dev tools, in order to have posted the above 2  error messages. He just interpreted them incorrectly, everyones got to start somewhere

Comment: @Turnip you're right, I just didn't notice the console message. Such a dummy question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open up the dev tool console on that link you've shared, here's the error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://zkid18.github.io/data_visualization_project/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'. 

This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

So in this case, the solution is to just load your external resources over HTTPS, because this is what GitHub is hosted on. For example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**If a page is loaded over HTTPS then every resource it uses should also be loaded over HTTPS.**

Reason behind this is, that otherwise a man-in-the-middle could replace resources (or ones that exploit buffer overflow issues in browsers to execute code) and scripts with ones that do different things (such as leak data to the third party).

You can read more about this [in this article on the Mozilla site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content).